# How can I remove the last line of text of textView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextView`. I'm adding it some texts that written in my `UITextField` by using `append()` method. I'm trying to remove the last line of my `UITextView` but I found just `removeLast()` method. Is there any method in swift for removing just the last line or should I write a method myself for it? If I should write a method, how can I write?

As you see in the picture, what I'm trying to do is filling the `UITextField` and saving them to `UITextView`. When I press the "clear" button, I want it to remove just the last line of `UITextView` (in this picture it is Jane Doe UNKNOWN).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dpt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton) {
        textView.text.append(firstName.text! + " " + lastName.text! + " " + dpt.text! + "\n")
    }

    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIButton) {
        firstName.text = " "
        lastName.text = " "
        dpt.text = " "
    }
}
```

[image: The image of my project.]

Comment: Show some relevant code in your question (as text). And clearly define what you mean by "last line" because there are two possible meanings.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by the last line of your text view. Obviously you mean the last line of text contents from your text view. Do you add lines that end with newline characters? What if a "line" of text (a block of text delimited with a newline) wraps to more than one display line? Is that 1 line, or multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your new information; I would suggest that you are actually wanting to be able to store a group of information (first name, last name and department) and delete the group as a whole. It may be more efficient to store the information as a struct and then store the people in an array. Then you can display the people in the array and manipulate them more easily. For example inside your class:

```
  struct Person {
    var first: String
    var last: String
    var dept: String
    }

// Declare an empty array of people
var arrayOfPeople: [Person] = []

@IBAction fun save(_ sender: UIButton) {
     let newPerson = Person(first: firstName.text, last: lastName.text, dept: dpt.text)
     arrayOfPeople.append(newPerson)
}
```

Then you can manipulate the array easily, and have a separate function to display the results of the array however you like (eg, in a textView if you really want; more commonly in a table)

Comment: I did what you said but I didn't figure out that how can I print the indices in the textView.

Comment: Making array is the best way I think. I set clear and save according to the array list. Now, when I click save button texts are shown in the textView as [Assignment02.ViewController.Person(first: "Halil", last: "ÇİFTTUR", dept: "CMPE")]. How can I set the text as Halil ÇİFTTUR CMPE

Comment: You can access the struct from the array by setting the text to: (for example) - let string = arrayOfPeople[0].first + " " + arrayOfPeople[0].last + " " + arrayOfPeople[0].dept and adding the string to the textfield. Consider trying a textbook like "Everyone can code" - the free one from Apple, to help you through this sort of stuff. It's a great textbook!

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, you are adding text from a textField into a textView using append(), and you wish to be able to remove the text added in this way.
One approach would be to save the text in the textView prior to adding the new text, and you could display this again in the textView to "remove the last line", eg:

```
var textPriorToAppend = textView.text
// Then append text
// If you want to revert to previous text
textView.text = textPriorToAppend
```

Comment: That would work but would duplicate a lot of data. If the OP adds text delimited with newline characters then there are much more efficient ways of doing this. (Searching backwards to the previous newline building a range, and deleting that range of text)

Comment: I described my question again could you look at now ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe creating an extension for UITextview or String

```
extension String { 
    func removeLastLine()->String {
        var comps = self.split(separator: "\n")
        comps.removeLast()
        var outputString = ""
        var br = ""
        for sub in comps {
            outputString.append(br+String(sub))
            br = "\n"
        }
        return outputString
    }
}


 extension TextView { 
    func removeLastLine(){
        var comps = self.text.split(separator: "\n")
        comps.removeLast()
        var outputString = ""
        var br = ""
        for sub in comps {
             outputString.append(br+String(sub))
            br = "\n"
        }
        self.text = outputString
    }
}
```